# How can I have a pulse of 30V at .7A for 30ms then a holding current of 3V at 50mA for as long as I want?

Tags: voltage

How is this possible with either controller, microcontroller or a circuit?

Comment: Don't get to choose both voltage and current, your load dictates the relation of V - I. Pick either a voltage pulse or a current pulse.

Comment: For best efficiency, use two supplies (+30, +30), 2 resistors and 2 relays.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to get a high voltage/current drive for a relay coil and then drop to a minimum holding current ....if that's true, then read this: http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/what-s-all-solenoid-driver-stuff-anyhow  ...a great exchange with Bob Pease.

Comment: What a great resource Jack.

Comment: @JackCreasey +1 for Bob Pease (RIP).

Answer (score 2):

If your load is something like a 40 ohm coil you can do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvo8gQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The top schematic is a dual high side driver that will run cool, but has a lot of parts. The second schematic is a much simpler low-side driver that burns a bunch of power in the 560 ohm resistor (should be rated for 2W) during hold.

Comment: https://www.schneideroptics.com/pdfs/industrial/Prontor_magnetic_shutter_0.pdf this is my load, a magnetic camera shutter, more than 50ms at 30V will kill the physical coils inside.

Comment: @angelbaums About what I expected. You might want to add some protection in case something goes wrong. A fuse in series with the high current line, for example. If properly sized it won't blow with the 50ms pulse, but will protect the coil if something goes wrong with the electronics. Maybe try 250mA (test using a resistor rather than the coil). Or (better) ask the manufacturer for a recommendation!